# SUPEE 9767 V2 fails Version 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, security, supee-9767

While installing new version of **SUPEE 9767 v2** patch I receive the below error

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 433
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..8618bca 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.2.1.1-1.6.0.2.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 340.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 607.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 502.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missed some patches. i am sure specially **SUPEE-7405 patch** missed.

you can check magereport.com any other old patches you are missed.

after apply patches are not work. check the files is in your folder app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: I have installed SUPEE 7405 v1 and SUPEE 7405 v1.1 but still SUPEE 9767 v2 patch fails. The file Image.php is not available in the path app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php

Comment: i will check and provide good Soluction to you :)

Comment: I have reverted SUPEE 7405 v1 and V1.1 and again installed those patches . I could able to see Image.php in the path app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/.

Comment: Now i installed SUPEE 9767 . I receive the below error

Comment: patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 340.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 607.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej

Comment: I have not applied 8788 v2 patch  and after applying SUPEE 8788 . SUPEE 9767 v2 patch  works!

Comment: Glad to here that I will update in Ans. Please accept :) . So This question is consider as close.

Comment: Thanks for Accept ans. If any question please post i will ans :)